# Why phoneState receiver gets empty incoming number

Tags: android, phone-state-listener

I want to block outgoing&incoming calls if a phone number is not in applications white list and there is more than one broadcast, and the first one has empty incoming number so that the call does not blocked and in most times it works fine because receiver gets the incoming number. Why it is empty number and how I can handle the empty broadcast?

```
public class CallServiceReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private TelephonyManager telephony;
private ITelephony telephonyService;

private Context context;

public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {


    this.context = context;

    if(!intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")){
        return;
    }
    telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(new TellListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

private class TellListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                if (incomingNumber == null || incomingNumber.equals("")) {
                    return;
                }
                    try {
                        inComingCallAuthorization(((ParentalControl)context.getApplicationContext()).makeCheckPhoneNumber(incomingNumber));
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.i("anarestan", "Call End" + incomingNumber);

                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                if (incomingNumber == null || incomingNumber.equals("")) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onCallStateChanged:  offhook");
                    outGoinCallAuthorization(((ParentalControl)context.getApplicationContext()).makeCheckPhoneNumber(incomingNumber));
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

    }
}
```

manifest

```
    <receiver android:name=".reciver.CallServiceReciver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this kind of approach. You need a BroadcastReceiver to intercept the NEW_OUTGOING_CALL Intent, but making sure to set the priority of your Intent filter to "-1". To abort the outbound call you'll need to call "setResultData(null)".

Longer explanation: this specific Intent is "Ordered". This means that this intent respects the "Priority" you assign to process it. So if your priority is the highest you will be the first to ise/manage it, and then you change its value to make the others intent-listeners using a changed and not-working intent.